# Oracle SQL - How to aggregate rows with the same value in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help. Have done this when using aggregating functions but since I am not using them here don`t know how to do it.

`ID                  num1 num2 num3 num4`

`180919113541070      0     0    0   4`

`180919113541070      0     0    0   0`

`180919113541070      4     0    0   0`

this is a simple select 
select * 
from tableX
order by ID;

I would like this data to appear in one row as below:

`ID                  num1 num2 num3 num4`

`180919113541070       4    0    0    4`

and not even have rows where all are 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function

```
select id,sum(num1) num1,sum(num2) num2,
sum(num3) num3,sum(num4) num4 from t group by id
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you. Easy

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want simple aggregation:

```
select id, max(num1) as num1, max(num2) as num2, max(num3) as num3, max(num4) as num4
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you!! Should`ve realized this myself but you helped a lot.